# Are there any issues switching a user from a roaming profile to a local profile?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, profile, roaming-profile

We have a Windows Server 2003 environment with XP Professional laptops.

If I switch a user from a roaming profile to a local profile in active directory, by clearing the profile path, will this cause any problems on the laptop the user always uses?  (They only use one single laptop - the roaming profile setting was set by their previous IT company.)

I.e. would it cause a new profile on the laptop to be created when they log on next or anything silly like that?

I see lots of information changing from local to roaming but not from roaming to local.

Comment: Do they have Application data redirect folder too ?
Roaming profile prevent loose of profile data and documents on the desktop if the laptop is stolen. Save also favorites, application settings & co. Even if users are using one computer, roaming profile can help a lot. Laptop are often stolen, and asking users to save on their own is not easy.

Comment: Valid point about losing data/settings.  However, the performance hit is reallllly outweighing the benefits of having roaming profiles enabled in this case.  We just want to disable is altogether.  Application data is currently stored within the roaming profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can tell you is that I have done it and encountered no issues at all.

Of course that doesn't mean that there might not be possible issues.